# tsc seemingly not picking up "exclude" options fro tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, angular, tsc

I am struggling to get tsc to pick up my tsconfig.json file and compile my .ts files. it runs into duplication errors which I am trying to avoid with my tsconfig.json.

I have:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
typings.json
typings /
    main/ ...etc
    browser/ ...etc
    main.d.ts
    browser.d.ts
src / ...   <source files in here.>
```

My typings.json looks like:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and in my package.json / tests object I have:

```
 "tsc": "tsc",
```

So I would expect my tsconfig.json to tell tsc to ignore the main.d.ts and the other definitions in main... Avoiding type definition collisions is explained a little more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#typings)

So, when I run `npm run tsc`, I would expect tsc to ignore main.d.ts and everything in main, but it doesn't.

I have seen other issues where [tsc ignores tsconfig.json when specific files are defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5497), but I don't have that case here.

Why is my tsconfig.json being ignored? Why is tsc being so mean to it?!

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Oh by the way, the errors are just several lines of errors like this - errors occur for both main and browser folders:

```
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2067,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PassThrough'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2072,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'showHidden'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2073,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'depth'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2074,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'colors'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2075,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'customInspect'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2136,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2144,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isRaw'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2146,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isTTY'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2149,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'columns'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2150,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'rows'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2151,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'isTTY'.
typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts(2158,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
```

### Edit:

After swapping to exlcude browser and browser.d.ts in my tsconfig.json and referring to typings/main.d.ts in my reference bath in `src/typings.d.ts`, I just get these errors:

```
src/typings.d.ts(3,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type 'NodeModule', but here has type '{ id: string; }'.
typings/main.d.ts(1,1): error TS6053: File 'typings/main/ambient/angular-protractor/index.d.ts' not found.
typings/main.d.ts(5,1): error TS6053: File 'typings/main/ambient/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts' not found.
```

Comment: Which files are duplicated? And which version of tsc do you have (`tsc -v`)? There are some changes between 1.6 and 1.8 in the `exclude` syntax

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671555/duplicate-identifier-for-angular2-typescript-files/36716815#36716815

Comment: I'm running on 1.8.10 it seems. I had read that about the changed for >= 1.8 - I didn't think what I had would be affected.... I could obviosuly be wrong!

In terms of that answer - I don't use any **s in my excludes array. Further, Im not getting any errors about my source code, just about my type definition files :(.. I hadn't seen that question though so thank you.

Comment: Can you add at least one error-message, this will perhaps help me.

Comment: I've added a sample :)

Comment: Do you have some `reference path` where you reference this in your code? What happens if you exclude the browser folder and file instead?

Comment: Yes In my src/typings.d.ts file, i have path="/../typings/main.d.ts"

I've swapped out the reference to refer to main and also excluded browser instead and now get just the errors that I've edited into the bottom of the question

Comment: For node error you may add below in your d.ts file or you may include typings for node, interface NodeModule {
    id: string;
}
declare var module: NodeModule;  For other errors  have you checked if the files are present

Comment: That's the odd thing, why is it looking in angular-potractor and selenium-webdriver when they are not in my typings.json?

Comment: Oh sorry I was being dumb. It references them in main.d.ts! Can anyone explain to me why swapping to excluding browser instead of main solved my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that you referenced the excluded main.d.ts somewhere. This will be loaded from tsc and so you have your dublicates.

Comment: Yes, you're essentially right. I still had that reference path in my src/typings.d.ts file that was referencing the (i thought) excluded main.d.ts file. After removing this reference, I could put it back to excluding main and main.d.ts.